# This and this - 5 cryptograms

Tags: cipher

Here are some cryptograms for you to solve:

1. `084 104 105 115 032 105 115 032 116 104 101 032 102 105 114 115 116 032 099 114 121 112 116 111 103 114 097 109 032 105 110 032 116 104 101 032 115 101 114 105 101 115 046 013 010`
2. `0114040020080919000919002008050014052420`
3. `tvpbb ftjrw pt hcvm fvbh yllbvtcb tnpd J`
4. `Bsfesutid tin s liteilsht  hi!` (the double spaces are intentional)
5. `1111200021001213010020002110311112102011311012110201!`

Comment: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1717/4551

Comment: Point 4: The double space is nowhere to be found? Between which characters is this double space?

Comment: @JBSregath it is between "lieteilsht" and "hi!", I edited the question changing the quotes in code-blocks, that should solve the problem.

Comment: meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1717/4551 mentions that "Before any hints appear, the puzzle is way too hard." I'm sorry, but I think most are not that hard except for 4 (which actually uses a fairly common encryption method).

Comment: but in this case i think i'll stop making these cryptograms since they are not welcomed anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the green check.  I don't think the message from @xnor was that these were too hard.  I think the message was to try to make them more interesting.  Perhaps with a surprising twist (but include some clues if decoding will not be intuitive).  You are very welcome to post more cryptograms - trying to increase the puzzle "quality".

Comment: Yes, Len said it well. These codes are pretty standard ideas, and that's what makes them solvable with short texts and no additional hints. You can extend them with more novel ideas. See my [meta answer](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1719/4551).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cryptogram 4 is:

> **But i still finished this set!**
>
>  encoded with 6 column transposition per this sequence:
>  1    6   11  16  21  26  2   7   12  17  22  27  3   8   13  18  23  28  4   9   14  19  24  29  5   10  15  20  25  30

Cryptogram 5 is:

> **Hope you had fun!**
>
>  encoded with Morse code (0 is dash, 1 is dot, 2 is letter space, 3 is word space).

Comment: I accepted this answer as it solved the hardest problems in the series. But everyone has contributed, so i'll upvote the answers.

Answer (score 6):

3)

> I don't actually have much to write about

the method

> Reverse the sentence. and then I noticed it was pretty much readable already. To get the real sentence replace every vowel in the solution with it's next letter in the alphabet

Answer (score 4):

In progress... :)

1)

> This is the first cryptogram in the series.

method

> (Ascii character numbers)

Answer (score 2):

2.)

> AND THIS IS THE NEXT

Method:

> Treat each pair of digits left to right as position of the corresponding letter in the alphabet, 00 = SPACE; 01 = A, 02 = B, 03 = C, ...